# C# MySQL SImple Membership Provider

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webmatrix

I am building a simple c# web application (NOT MVC) using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition).  My database is the latest version of MySQL, as is the MySQL Connector I have installed.

I have modified my Web.config file to use WebMatrix Simple Membership Provider, with MySQL.

Here is my Web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
        <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate" validation="SHA1"/>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
          <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer"/>
    <add name="RP" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=my_db; uid=my_uid; pwd=my_password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.WebData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). -->
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
    <!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 3, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 and 2 references relink
         to MVC 3 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it.
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
     -->
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
    <settings>
      <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
           before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
           be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
      <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
          <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
            <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
          </trustedProviders>-->
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
               with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
  <uri>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
         which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
         It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

The simple membership provider is set up to automatically create the Membership database tables, which it did successfully.

I am able to select data from my database and display.

However, when I go to register a user (using a webpage created automatically by the Simple Membership Provider), I get an error.

Membership Data, through the associated Simple Provider is written to two tables by default, a userprofile table, and a webpages_membership table.

When I hit the "Submit" button data is written correctly to the userprofile table, however I get this error when writing data to the webpages_membership table:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('brian@myurl.com')' at line 1

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('brian@robeyspub.com')' at line 1

Source Error: 


Line 50:                 {
Line 51:                     bool requireEmailConfirmation = !WebMail.SmtpServer.IsEmpty();
Line 52:                     var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, requireEmailConfirmation);
Line 53:                     if (requireEmailConfirmation)
Line 54:                     {

Source File: c:\Users\brian\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Robey's Pub VS2015 Razor\Account\Register.cshtml    Line: 52 

Stack Trace: 


[MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('brian@robeyspub.com')' at line 1]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +272
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +68
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +17
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +110
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +783
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1564
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +112
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] args) +98
   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +29
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId(IDatabase db, String userTableName, String userNameColumn, String userIdColumn, SimpleMembershipProviderCasingBehavior casingBehavior, String userName) +217
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken) +158
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken) +51
   ASP._Page_Account_Register_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\brian\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Robey's Pub VS2015 Razor\Account\Register.cshtml:52
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +177
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +83
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +103
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +101
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +110
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

---

More information;

The program errors on this statement (this is an automatically (computer) generated statement, created by the Simple Membership Provider:

var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, requireEmailConfirmation);

Here are the error details:

---

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled by user code   ErrorCode=-2147467259
```

HResult=-2147467259
Message=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('brian@robeyspub.com')' at line 1   Number=1064
Source=MySql.Data

StackTrace:
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
           at WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] args)
           at WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
           at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId(IDatabase db, String userTableName, String userNameColumn, String userIdColumn, SimpleMembershipProviderCasingBehavior casingBehavior, String userName)
           at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)
           at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateAccount(String userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)
           at ASP._Page_Account_Register_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\brian\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Robey's Pub VS2015 Razor\Account\Register.cshtml:line 52
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
           at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext)

```
InnerException:
```

Comment: I'm currently in the process of replacing SQL Server with MySQL in my project and am running into the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have Mistake in your query 
here Please check your query once 
'[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('brian@robeyspub.com')'

check that you are using single quotes so

This 
'[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('
This will be first string
and this will be second
')'

but what system interpreted 
brian@robeyspub.com

Do one thing use debugger and check your query and run it into mysql you will get what error you are getting
Thanks

Comment: The problem is... that's not "my" query... That query is derived from the DLL associated with the Simple Membership Provider.  I cannot change the query in any way.

Comment: Clearly your error is saying

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([Email]) = UPPER('brian@robeyspub.com')' at line 1]

Comment: I have the error, but I cannot post it to a comment, as it says there are "too many characters" in my comment.

I am unsure how to post my error...

Comment: @BrianAshcraft You would edit that information into your question.